# How do I get a function's output characters to be automatically counted in python?

Tags: python, function, count

I am trying to print the number of characters that are present in the output my function gives. in this case I'm looking for 90 as "lowercase" 10 times is 90 characters. I'm not really sure what to try, please advise.

```
num=10
def func(word, add=5, freq=1):
    print(word*(freq+add))
test=func("lowercase", num)
print(test, num)
count(test)
```

When I tried to use the "count" function, I got the below error:

traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Tzvi Aryeh\Documents\python programs#optional Parameters Tutorial #1.py", line 18, in 
count(test)
^^^^^
NameError: name 'count' is not defined. Did you mean: 'round'?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to modify your function so that it `return`s the output instead of `print`ing it:

```
num=10
def func(word, add=5, freq=1):
    return word*(freq+add)

test=func("lowercase", num)
print(test, num)
print(len(test))
```

With your original code, `func` would directly `print` the output and then return `None` (meaning that `test` becomes `None`, which you can't do anything with -- when you try to `print` it after having called your function, you'll just see `None`).

The above code `return`s the string, which is then assigned to `test`.  The line `print(test, num)` prints:

```
lowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercaselowercase 10
```

and the line `print(len(test))` prints the `len` (length) of `test`:

```
99
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. out of curiosity, why isn't "word*" part of the parenthesis in the return statement?

Comment: If you do `(word*freq+add)` then the order of operations means you first do `word*freq` and then `+add`.  That will give you an error because `word*freq` is a `str` and `add` is an `int`, and the `+` operator isn't supported for those two types.  You want to add the two ints together first, and then multiply the string by the int (which *is* allowed).

Comment: Note that the parens in that statement are not part of the `return` (because `return` is not a function call), they're just used to enforce a particular order of operations in the `word*(freq+add)` expression.  If you didn't need that, you wouldn't have any parens on that line at all.